# move div with mouse and its content clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Div which moves with the mouse cursor. In DIV, I have 2 links and I want to click on them also, but the Div is movable, it moves with the mouse so when I want to click on Links (in that div) , DIV move far away from the cursor.

My CODE:

```
<div class="myDiv">
  Click to View<br>
  <a href="#linkA">Link A</a><br>
  <a href="#linkB">Link B</a>
</div>

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
  $('.myDiv').css({
     left:  e.pageX + 50,
     top:   e.pageY
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hbd/zo0csLx5/

Comment: what kind of behavior do you really want?

Comment: when mouse cursor moves to DIV's direction, the "mousemove" behavior stops. Need to define an area around DIV, so when cursor is on that area movable-behavior stops and cursor enter on that div and clicks on the links..after leaving that area, DIV should again move with the cursor.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zo0csLx5/1/

Comment: @nevermind thanks, great. But not exactly this, actually I want that DIV 50px behind the cursor, when cursor come closer to DIV's area, div stops moving. Cursor clicks on links and leave Div area but when cursor cross that 50px distance, div starts chasing it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my kind of unreadable code, but it might give you an idea.

```
var cursorPos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    offset: 50
};

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    var myDiv = $(".myDiv"),
      myDivData = {
        width: myDiv.innerWidth(),
        height: myDiv.innerHeight(),
        posX: myDiv.offset().left,
        posY: myDiv.offset().top,
      };

    // Check if the cursor is out of a given area
    if (!((e.pageX >= (myDivData.posX - cursorPos.offset) && e.pageX <= (myDivData.posX + myDivData.width + cursorPos.offset)) && 
          (e.pageY >= (myDivData.posY - cursorPos.offset) && e.pageY <= (myDivData.posY + myDivData.height + cursorPos.offset)))
       ) {

        // Check if it moved horizontally
        if (e.pageX > (myDivData.posX + myDivData.width)) {
            myDiv.css({
                left:  (e.pageX - myDivData.width - cursorPos.offset),
            });
        }
        else if (e.pageX < myDivData.posX)
            myDiv.css({
                left:  e.pageX + cursorPos.offset,
            });

        // Check if it moved vertically
        if (e.pageY > (myDivData.posY + myDivData.height))
            myDiv.css({
                top: (e.pageY - myDivData.height - cursorPos.offset)
            });
        else if (e.pageY < myDivData.posY)
            myDiv.css({
                top:   e.pageY + cursorPos.offset
            });

    }
    cursorPos.x = e.pageX;
    cursorPos.y = e.pageY;
});
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zo0csLx5/3/)

Comment: hi @nersoh, sir please take a look at my demo [http://jsfiddle.net/hbd/jfPZH/449/](http://jsfiddle.net/hbd/jfPZH/449/) , i want to add transition or smoothness effect in it.